# In Java: convert an array of floats to bytes and vice versa

Tags: java

I'm just returning to Java after a multi-decade hiatus -- there are some nice new packages, such as java.nio.

I need to convert an array of floats into bytes and vice versa.  The `floatToBytes()` function feels okay, but I'm pretty certain that `bytesToFloats()` could be implemented better.  Thoughts?

(P.S.: ignore the `public`, `protected` etc -- this code is wrapped inside a class...)

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

    protected static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = Float.SIZE / 8;

    public static byte[] floatsToBytes(float[] floats){
        ByteBuffer buffer = 
                ByteBuffer.allocate(BYTES_PER_FLOAT * floats.length).
                order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        for (float f : floats) {
            buffer.putFloat(f);
        }
        return buffer.array();
    }
    
    protected static float[] bytesToFloats(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes.length % BYTES_PER_FLOAT != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal length");
        }
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        int n_floats = bytes.length / BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
        float[] floats = new float[n_floats];
        for (int i=0; i<n_floats; i++) {
            floats[i] =  buffer.getFloat(i * BYTES_PER_FLOAT);
        }
        return floats;
    }
```

I also note that there's a `FloatBuffer` class -- would that be appropriate here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is way more verbose than it needs to be.

First of all, `BYTES_PER_FLOAT` is unnecessary.  You could simply use [`Float.BYTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#BYTES), a built-in constant.

Secondly, the initial ordering of a `ByteBuffer` is always `BIG_ENDIAN`, so you don't need to set this explicitly.

Finally, as [dariosicily](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/246267/100620) indicated, using `asFloatBuffer()` allows bulk operations, but additionally, you should "Invocation chaining" to make the code significantly shorter:

```
class Convert {

    public static byte[] floatsToBytes(float[] floats) {
        byte bytes[] = new byte[Float.BYTES * floats.length];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asFloatBuffer().put(floats);
        return bytes;
    }
    
    public static float[] bytesToFloats(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes.length % Float.BYTES != 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal length");
        float floats[] = new float[bytes.length / Float.BYTES];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asFloatBuffer().get(floats);
        return floats;
    }
}
```

Comment: More compact code than my answer and I completely missed the reference to the implicit order ,  from documentation seems that `Float.BYTES` constant has been introduced from java 8 version while it does not exist in java previous versions.

Comment: Perfect use of chaining -- thank you.  In this specific case, it's important that the future developer (or "future me") know the byte ordering, so I inserted `.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)` into the chain.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome again to Code Review, not my field but from a not so clear documentation it seems that you can rewrite your `bytesToFloats` method using the `FloatBuffer` class like below, using the [asFloatBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asFloatBuffer()) method from `ByteBuffer` class:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
FloatBuffer fb = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
```

After you have to *back* the `FloatBuffer` buffer allocating a new `float` array like below:

```
float[] floats = new float[bytes.length / BYTES_PER_FLOAT];
fb.get(floats);
```

Then your method can be rewritten like below:

```
protected static float[] bytesToFloats(byte[] bytes) {

    if (bytes.length % BYTES_PER_FLOAT != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Illegal length");
    }
    
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    FloatBuffer fb = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
    float[] floats = new float[bytes.length / BYTES_PER_FLOAT]; 
    
    fb.get(floats);

    return floats;

}
```

In alternative to the `bytes.length / BYTES_PER_FLOAT` the `fb.limit()` method seems returning the same result, moreover it is bound directly to the `FloatBuffer` fb used.